# Reading from CGI Post Form

Tags: c, post, cgi

I've tried using fgets(username, 20, stdin); fgets(password, 20, stdin); to take in input for my C program when passing the POST form's input to it but it adds on & at the end of the username value... How can I work around this?

I guess my question is: How do I parse through the inputs of username and password such that I only get what I actually typed into the boxes instead of some messed-up strings?

Answer (score 1):

That's because fgets will get as more as 19 chars from the stream, it does not stop at newline or '&' in your case. You could try to use sscanf for formatted input, like following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *form = "user=foo&password=bar";

    char user[32];
    char passwd[32];

    int ret = sscanf(form, "user=%[^&]&password=%[^&]", user, passwd);
    if (ret != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid form\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("user is %s, passwd is %s\n", user, passwd);
    return 0;
}
```